# Implement a list using an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to write a program in which we have a list of temperatures(Double) and each day(string), the list needs to be implemented using an array of objects.

I do not understand how I can create a list with doubles and strings, and how to implement it using an array of objects.

So far this is what I have for my program:

```
public class dailyTemperature 
{

    //variables
    double temperature;
    String day;

    //getTemp & setTemp methods
    public double getTemp()
    {
      return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemp(double newTemp)
    {
      temperature = newTemp;
    }

    //getDay & setTEmp methods
    public String getDay()
    {
      return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String newDay)
    {
      day = newDay;
    }



}
```

However how can I create a list with doubles and strings and how to implement the list using an array of objects? I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Encapsulate your pair of information. Create an array of the encapsulation type, add elements.

Comment: Make a class with two fild temperature and day.

Comment: Hi Sophia, I noticed that you may benefit from reading the help section. If you tell us what you've tried, post snippets, and try to ask a more focused question, I'm sure somebody will be able to help! Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: So now that you have your `DailyTemperature` class, this is the thing that you need to make a list of, or an array of.  Since your instructions are to implement this with an array, you might create what you need with something like `DailyTemperature[] myList = new DailyTemperature[100];`, where you specify how big you actually need your array to be.

Comment: @DavidWallace Would I add the days of the week and the temperature as I normally add to arrays? I guess I am a little confused on what is an array of objects and implement a list using an array of objects

Comment: Sure.  After you've created the array itself, you still need to create each object that you're going to put in the array.  You should probably make a constructor for your `DailyTemperature` class, similar to the one in Hello_Everyone's answer.  Then you could do something like `myList[0] = new DailyTemperature("Monday", 15.3);` for each temperature that you want to add.  Be careful though - Hello_Everyone chose to answer the question in C#, not in Java; I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

```
// -- if you use lombok: ---
// @Data
// @AllArgsConstructor
// -------------------------
public class TempOfTheDay {
    private double temp;

    private String day; // I would use and int (see Calendar.MONDAY etc)

    // ctors, getters, setters, ... (if you don't use lombok :p)
}
```

and put that in an array:

```
final TempOfTheDay[] myArray = new TempOfTheDay[]{ 
    new TempOfTheDay(127.0, "monday") 
};
```

Comment: Also you should implement valid hasCode method(see Java documentation to figure out how should be done hashCode), because if you store this object onto any sorted collectio which use hasCode method inside - you can lose some advantage or get an Exception.

Comment: @ProtosZetZ `@Data` does that for me ;)

Comment: sorry, I don't know this annotation... before. So I should read documentation =)

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar in C#.  Here it is translated into Java.

You can create a class containing the information for each entry, for example:

```
    public class DayTemperature       
    {
            private String day;
            private int temp;

            public DayTemperature(String day, int temp)
            {
                this.day = day;
                this.temp = temp;
            }
    }
```

Then in your program you can instantiate this class, give those some values and then put the object into a list:

```
    DayTemperature  entry1 = new DayTemperature ("Monday", 123);
    DayTemperature  entry2 = new DayTemperature ("Tuesday", 23);
    DayTemperature  entry3 = new DayTemperature ("Wednesday", 50);

    List<DayTemperature> list1 = new ArrayList<DayTemperature>();
    list1.add(entry1);
    list1.add(entry2);
    list1.add(entry3);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The same commend as for @RC answer

Comment: java.util.List is an interface, so new List() won't work. Could be LinkedList or ArrayList, the latter using an array of objects internally, which would fulfill the demand of the question..

Comment: also `String` with a capital `S`

Comment: Thank you everyone, the above code is actually written in C# but same idea in Java

Comment: @Hello_Everyone Oh I didn't see the `.Add()` ;) Note that the question is tagged java so perhaps an edit stating that your answer is c# might be useful

Answer (score 0):

You have several posibilities :)

The bad one:

```
Object[] result = new Object[1];
result[0] = new Object[]{"1.1", Double.valueOf(15,3)};

System.out.println("Day " + result[0][0] + " was temperature: " + result[0][1]);
```

Better one:

```
class DayTemperature
{
  final Strting date;
  final Double temperature;
  DayTemperature(String aDate, Double aTemperature)
  {
     date = sDate;
     temperature = aTemperature;
  }
  String getDate() { return date;}
  Double getTemperature() { return temperature;}
}

final DayTemperature[] result = new DayTemperature[1]; 
result[0] = new DayTemperature("1.1", Double.valueOf(12.5));

System.out.println("Day " + result[0].getDate() + " was temperature: " + result[0].getTemperature());
```

Best I would suggest to you Map:

```
Map<String, Double> result = new HashLinkedMap<String, Double>(1);
result.put("1.1", Double.valueOf(12,5));

for(Map.Entry<String, Double> e : result.entrySet())
{
  System.out.println("Day " + e.getKey() + " was temperature: " + e.getValue());
}
```

Hopefully this will help.